# Profile picture in formula field

Tags: formula-field, user, image-formula

I'm trying to get the user's profile picture to display in a page layout through the use of a formula field (image function). But I can't find the profile picture in the user object. Is it possible at all to make use of the profile pic this way?

Comment: No there is no option to refer user profile image in formula field.. you need vf page here..  https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000hk8OAAQ

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to use a Visualforce page to display the pic. Here is an example showing the profile pic on an employee record (custom object).

```
<apex:page standardController="Employee__c">
    <br />
    <apex:image value="{!Employee__c.user__r.FullPhotoUrl}"/> 
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Thanks but I don't want to change the page layout for a VF page. Any ideas how I can keep the default page layout?

Comment: You can use the VF as a component in your page layout. When you've created the page, it shows up in the list of available VF pages in the page layout editor

Comment: It's working! Thanks Fred, will vote for your answer as soon as I have enough credits

Comment: This is SO close to what I'd want.... a Formula field with IMAGE() code to pull in their Photo.    Any takers?   >:-)

Comment: @AMM I'm afraid it's not possible to use the photo url in a formula field. Hence the VF component. Isn't that working for you?

Comment: Can I put a VF component in a Report?   In a field?   My experience is no, but I don't know *everything* just yet so... I'd love to be shown otherwise.   :-)

Comment: What's frustrating as heck is doing a dataexport from User and seeing the "field" that has the image URL in it (FullPhotoUrl).  (sigh)  It's a tease.

Answer (score 1):

I am able to get the URL of FullPhoto and SmallPhoto of User as follows:

```
 select Id,FullPhotoUrl,SmallPhotoUrl from User
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way!

1. Create a custom field.
2. Write a trigger to populate the custom field using the below query,

   User p = [Select Name, SmallPhotoUrl, FullPhotoUrl From User where
   Id=:uName];

Comment: what that custom field will contain differently from FullPhotoUrl  ?

Comment: If it is a standard detail page, populating this custom field will help creating a formula.
If it is a visfualforce page, then there is no need of the field.